# Need Background Picture for Chat screen for different screen aspect ratios and Portrait and Landscape mode

Tags: flutter

We would like to use a background picture for the chat screen. For that purpose we created a tile-able picture. Mobile supports many aspect ratios and Portrait and Landscape. What would be a good way in Flutter to support that use case? One Idea would be to join the tiles and crop a picture in run time for the background. Is that possible? Is there direct flutter support for that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the flutter docs about responsive apps

[Creating Responsive Apps](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Creating-Responsive-Apps)

Also, take a look at the MediaQueryData class that captures device orientation. You could switch backgrounds by looking at these properties

[MediaQueryData](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData-class.html)

Comment: I did read this and its a good start, thanks. Could u please be a bit more explicit how you would solve this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for landscape and potrait and different device resolutions. The opacity could be set directly on the picture to save that layer in runtime. Please make sure that you provide the background in different resolutions. https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/

Note: renderMessageListContent is the content in the foreground!

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => new Stack(children: <Widget>[
        new Positioned.fill(
            child: new Opacity(
          opacity: 0.2,
          child: new Image.asset(
            'assets/chat_background.png',
            repeat: ImageRepeat.repeat,
            fit: BoxFit.none
          ),
        )),
        new Opacity(
            opacity: 0.15,
            child: new Container(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor)),
        renderMessageListContent
      ]);
```